# I'm trying to collect some YouTube usage data so I can run clustering for personality types

Tags: data-request

I'm in the initial stages of a project and I are looking to just collect some initial data based on youtube watch category usage. Requirements are: you have a google acc linked to your youtube acc with likes, watch laters, etc.

http://youtubeprofile.herokuapp.com/

Right now we've (poorly) manually created some personality archetypes (wtf is clubber/basic anyways???) but our plan is to cluster the data to provide more insightful information. If you guys can help out, maybe OP will deliver...